# Gurobi in Matlab without objective function

Tags: matlab, gurobi

I am using Gurobi in Matlab to determine whether a system of linear equalities and linear inequalities has at least one solution. I don't have an objective function to minimise/maximise.

This is my code (I haven't posted the actual content of the matrices `Aineq, Aeq, bineq, beq`)

```
clear model;
model.A=[Aineq; Aeq];
model.obj=[]; 
model.sense=[repmat('<', size(Aineq,1),1); repmat('=', size(Aeq,1),1)];
model.rhs=full([bineq; beq]); 
params.outputflag = 0; 
result=gurobi(model, params);
if isfield(result,'x')
    exists=1;
else
    exists=0;
end
```

Question: what should I set as objective function? If I write `model.obj=[];` as above I get

```
Error using gurobi
Incorrect size(model.obj)
```

If I delete the model line I get

```
Error using gurobi
model must contain fields: A, obj, sense, and rhs
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387677/gurobi-with-java-without-objective-function) question is related to mine but it doesn't explain what to put in place of the objective function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have the needed reputation to comment, so this is an answer.

It's important that your matrix A is a sparse matrix, because Gurobi's MATLAB API only accepts sparse matrices: `model.A=sparse([Aineq; Aeq])`. Then it should work by just removing the line `model.obj = []` from your code. If no objective is passed to Gurobi, it will automatically use 0 as the objective function, so that your model will minimize 0 in subject to your constraints. In this case every feasible solution is optimal and satisfies your constraints. Alternatively, you could do this by hand with

```
model.obj = zeros(size(model.A, 2), 1);
```